# How to move private fields to the top of the class with ReSharper

Tags: resharper, code-formatting

I want to move all the private fields in a class to the top or at least to a block where they are gathered together.

Is there any quick way to achieve this with ReSharper?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You want the feature called *Cleanup Code*.

You can access it via

- <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>, according to my keyboard shortcuts, or
- the window menu *Resharper | Code | Cleanup code...*

Ensure that your profile has the option *Reorder members* selected.  If you want to change the way that the reordering works, you can, but it's a little involved.

You can also apply this across an entire project or the entire solution by right-clicking at the appropriate level in solution explorer and choosing the *Cleanup Code...* option from there.

Comment: If you are using the Visual Studio Resharper keyboard scheme then the keyboard shortcut you want is Ctrl+E, C or Ctrl+E, K for silent mode. (According to the cheat sheet I have in front of me)

Answer (score 1):

I answered a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/858652/resharper-how-to-force-introducing-new-private-fields-at-the-bottom-of-the-class/858715#858715). It's for putting them at the bottom, but should be enough information to get you set up too.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the Clean code options?

I believe you can set the behaviour there.

Kindness,

Dan